# Power[__] Pattern works like Level

Tags: pattern-matching

I came across this case:

```
expr = {x, Cos[Exp[x]], x^a}

Cases[expr, Power[__], -1]
(*{x,E,x,E^x,Cos[E^x],x,a,x^a}*)

Level[expr, -1]
(*{x,E,x,E^x,Cos[E^x],x,a,x^a}*)
```

What is going on here? Why `Power[__]` (or `Power[_]` ) Works like Level?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very simply `Power[__]` evaluates to `__` and `__` matches any expression:

```
expr = {x, Cos[Exp[x]], x^a};

Power[__]

Cases[expr, __, -1]
```

> ```
> __
>
> {x, E, x, E^x, Cos[E^x], x, a, x^a}
> ```

Comment: Hmm, Indeed very simply. Although I have came across such thing in the past and all I need to do to check is use Trace, I have missed that. Thinking of finding something new blinded me to realize the reality. what a shame ! I think I need to reconsider my ability in MMA :(

Comment: @Algohi We all get surprises from *Mathematica*.  It's just a matter of having a good set of diagnostic methods to determine the reason for the behavior.

Answer (score 3):

`_^_` instead of `Power[__]` may give you the result you desire. The issue is that all expressions strictly match themselves to the first power!

```
MatchQ[x, Power[__]]
```

> True

```
MatchQ[x, Power[_, 1]]
```

> True

```
MatchQ[x, _^_]
```

> False

Considering you example...

```
 expr = {x, Cos[Exp[x]], x^a}

 Cases[expr, _^_, -1] // InputForm
```

> {E^x, x^a}